# Retrieve sent emails

Tags: windows-10, imap, email-client, webmail

We have moved to another hosting provider.
The emails we have sent since have been delivered to the addressees.
However, the sent emails do not appear in any "Sent" folder in the local email client nor in webmail.
Is there a way to retrieve those sent emails on the hosting server?
Hosting provider uses PLESK.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Contact customer support of your previous su8pplier.

Answer (score 0):

The lost emails that have been sent but were not stored in webmail, have been retrieved in the local email folders.
From those folders we have copied the messages to the correct folders in each email account.